# How to choose spring configuration in runtime based on a tenant?

Tags: spring, grails, multi-tenant

I would like to be able to choose specific Spring (or Grails) context configuration based on the tenant that user belongs to in runtime. Let's say I use Spring Security and I retrieve tenantId during login.
Imagine now I have a two tenants and they pay different commission. How to inject specific service into a controller without too much plumbing? Here are two different contexts. So, I should inject different ExchangeService based on tenant.

```
@Configuration
public class FooTenant{
@Bean
public ExchangeService bar() {
  return new ZeroCommisionExchangeService ();
  }
}


@Configuration
public class BarTenant{
@Bean
public ExchangeService bar() {
  return new StandardCommisionExchangeService ();
  }
}
```

Edit:
I am aware I can obtain reference to Spring context and ask for service "manually", but I am looking for a more generic solution where this problematic is solved by IoC framework.

Comment: I deleted my answer, its interesting question and I am also curious to learn how it will work.

Comment: I think your answer was a valid, albeit last resort solution.

Comment: I'm looking for answers to this too. An option that comes to my mind is to have a prototyped bean that's configured with a factory-method, and receive arguments in runtime.

Comment: @SérgioMichels care to elaborate?

Comment: @Dan I transformed it to an answer. Let's see if more comes :-)

Comment: Why not create a Map in the config file. Key is tenant name, value is the service bean to use for that tenant. And then inject the map into the controller so it can lookup the service in the map without referring to the context.

Comment: @flup Because I wish controller to be injected, and not to implement plumbing look-up code itself.

Comment: I don't understand. I assume there's more than one tenant per JVM / context for else it'd be too easy. So then doesn't that mean that you'll have to do some manual lookup depending on, for example, a request's tenant?

Comment: exactly, I am asking how to customize spring DI to inject corresponding service based on tenant id. For web apps, tenant id can be placed inside the session, but for restful services tenant id has request scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of years ago we needed somthing like this but only for `DataSource`s and `ViewResolvers`. We developed a solution using spring' `TargetSource` solution. (Initially we used a `HotswappableTargetSource` but that wasn't adequate for our use-case.

The code we developed is availabe [here](https://github.com/mdeinum/spring-utils) in the **multi-tenant** directory.

It is fully configurable and flexible.

Basically what you do is you configura a `ContextSwappableTargetSource` and tell it what type of interface/class it needs to return.

```
<bean id="yourTentantBasedServiceId"  class="biz.deinum.multitenant.aop.target.ContextSwappableTargetSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ExchangeService" />
</bean>
```

The default is to lookup beans in the ApplicationContext based on the tenantId (see the `BeanFactoryTargetRegistry` for this). However you can specify one or more of those (we used a `JndiLookupTargetRegistry` to dynamically lookup datasource, which allowed use to add tenants on the fly without restarting the application).

If you explicitly configure a `BeanFactoryTargetRegistry` you can add a `prefix` and `suffix`.

```
<bean id="exchangeService"  class="biz.deinum.multitenant.aop.target.ContextSwappableTargetSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ExchangeService" />
    <property name="targetRegistry>
        <bean class="biz.deinum.multitenant.aop.target.registry.impl.BeanFactoryTargetRegistry">
           <property suffix="ExchangeService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now for foo it would lookup a bean named `fooExchangeService` and for bar `barExchangeService`.

The tenantId is stored in a `ThreadLocal` which is wrapped inside the `ContextHolder`. You need to find a way to fill and clear this thread local (in general a servlet `Filter` does that trick.

In your code you can now simply use the interface `ExchangeService` and at runtime based on the `tenantId` the correct implemenation will be looked up.

Also see http://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have different services already defined, you can get their bean from the context and use it. In my example, all the services have implementation of `serviceMethod` and based on some criteria pick your proper service. The only thing I am not sure is how `Multitenancy` might impact this.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

class ServiceManagerController {
    def serviceManager

    def index() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = grails.util.Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext
        serviceManager = ctx.getBean(params.serviceName); //firstService or secondService
        render serviceManager.serviceMethod()
    }
}
```

FirstService

```
class FirstService {

    def serviceMethod() {
        return "first"
    }
}
```

SecondService:

```
class SecondService {

    def serviceMethod() {
        return "second"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alidad, I am aware you can obtain app context and get hold of service "manually". I am looking for a way to do this on automagically on context side.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to swap beans instantiated in a spring context at runtime (`HotswappableTargetSource`), it is not meant for use cases such as yours.

Remember there is one Spring Context for your application, all threads use the same instances (in most cases), this implies when you swap out a bean implementation, you are affectively doing this for all your application's users. To prevent this, you run into issues of ensuring Thread Safety, employing Thread Locals, as listed in another answer.

While it is possible to continue this approach and arrive at an implementation that gets the job done, it would definitely be a very contrived way of solving this problem.

You should take a step back and look at your problem in a more wholesome, system wide design point of view. Bust out your patterns books and look at how this can be resolved, regardless of whether you use Spring or an other framework. Service Locator, Factory bean etc described in some of the answers above is a step in the correct direction.

Your Use Case is pretty common for multi-tenant applications. You need to narrow down things that are likely to change based on a tenantId versus things that are constant across.

For instance as mentioned in the question, each Tenant might have a different commission amount or even different algorithm for commission calculation. A simple solution to this would be to implement a `CommissionCalculationService` which accepts a `tenantId`, and any other domain object based on which commission is to be calculated, I would imagine this would be something like `Order` or `Sale`, whatever makes sense in your application.

You now need a `CommissionServiceFactory` or a `ServiceLocator` which will contain tenant specific implementations of the `CommissionCalculationService`. The `Service Locator` is instantiated when the Spring context loads, and is injected with implementation classes also at application startup.

When you want to calculate commission for a tenant, you basically obtain the `tenantId` from the user's login, pass the tenant id to your service locator, based on the `tenantId` passed, the service locator returns the appropriate instance of a Service Implementation. In your calling class, use this instance to calculate the commission for the tenant.

Another pattern to consider is the `Strategy Pattern`, or even `Template Pattern`.

Bottom line, even if you want tenant specific logic implemented cleanly, don't thing about changing the beans loaded in the context. Have classes in your context that can handle all your tenant specific logic. Rely on design patterns to use the correct bean from the context based on the tenant id.

I apologize if the answer was a little verbose, I felt it was needed to explain why I think updating beans in a loaded Spring Context is not the appropriate solution.

Comment: Don't see what my question has to do with swapping beans at runtime? Each tenant-specific service is just a bean registered in the context and it is looked up based on tenant id. You might as well look them up by the name and use it inside the single request.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming my comment in an answer, one possible solution is to create a spring factory bean, that receive all he needs to decide which service needs to be returned when creating the instance.

Translating to Grails:

```
public interface ChoosableServiceIntf {
  String getName();
}

class NormalService implements ChoosableServiceIntf {
  public String getName() {
    return getClass().name;
  }
}

class ExtendedService implements ChoosableServiceIntf {
  public String getName() {
    return getClass().name
  }
}

class ChoosableServiceFactory {

  static ChoosableServiceIntf getInstance(String decisionParam) {

    if(decisionParam == 'X') {
      return applicationContext.getBean('extendedService')
    }
    return applicationContext.getBean('normalService')
  }

  static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext
  }
}
```

Here we have two services and `ChoosableServiceFactory` is responsible to know witch is the correct one.

Then you will need to use the method `ApplicationContext#getBean(String, Object[])` to return the correct instance and will also make the factory `prototyped scope` because of the runtime params.

A controller to test it:

```
class MyController {

  def grailsApplication

  def index() {
    ChoosableServiceIntf service = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('choosableServiceFactory', ["X"] as Object[])
    ChoosableServiceIntf serviceNormal = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('choosableServiceFactory', ["N"] as Object[])

    render text: "#1 - ${service.class.name} , #2 - ${serviceNormal.class.name}"
  }
}
```

This will print `#1 - dummy.ExtendedService , #2 - dummy.NormalService`

The declaration of the beans will be:

```
choosableServiceFactory(ChoosableServiceFactory) { bean ->
  bean.scope = 'prototype'
  bean.factoryMethod = 'getInstance'
}
normalService(NormalService)
extendedService(ExtendedService)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
public class ConfigurableProxyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Object>, BeanNameAware {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider;

    private Class<?> proxyType;
    private String beanName;
    private Object object;
    private Object fallbackObject;
    private Object monitor = new Object();
    private ConfigurableProxy proxy;

    public ConfigurableProxyFactoryBean(Class<?> proxyType) {
        this.proxyType = proxyType;
    }

    public Object getFallbackObject() {
        return fallbackObject;
    }

    public void setFallbackObject(Object fallbackObject) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            this.fallbackObject = fallbackObject;
            if (proxy != null) {
                proxy.setFallbackObject(fallbackObject);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        beanName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            if (object == null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Class<Object> type = (Class<Object>)proxyType;
                proxy = new ConfigurableProxy(applicationContextProvider, beanName);
                proxy.setFallbackObject(fallbackObject);
                object = Proxy.newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                        new Class<?>[] { type }, proxy);
            }
            return object;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return proxyType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
   }
}

class ConfigurableProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    public ConfigurableProxy(ApplicationContextProvider appContextProvider, String beanName) {
        this.appContextProvider = appContextProvider;
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    private ApplicationContextProvider appContextProvider;
    private String beanName;
    private Object fallbackObject;

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        ApplicationContext appContext = appContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        String name = "$&&#" + beanName;
        Object bean = appContext.containsBean(name) ? appContext.getBean(name) : fallbackObject;
        return method.invoke(bean, args);
    }

    public void setFallbackObject(Object fallbackObject) {
        this.fallbackObject = fallbackObject;
    }
}
```

`ApplicationContextProvider` has implementation, that chooses `ApplicationContext` according to current tennant.

In XML configuration it is used like this:

```
<bean class="my.package.infrastructure.ConfigurableProxyFactoryBean" name="beanName">
  <constructor-arg>
    <value type="java.lang.Class">my.package.model.ServiceInterface</value>
  </constructor-arg>
  <property name="fallbackObject">
    <bean class="my.package.service.DefaultServiceImplementation"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And in tennant configuration that way:

```
<bean class="my.package.service.ServiceImplementationA" name="$&&#beanName"/>
```

To inject this service somewhere you just write:

```
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceInterface service;
}
```

Also you are to implement `ApplicationContextProvider`, I won't share mine. It is not very hard to implement. For example, your implementation can just store context in `ThreadLocal`. And you create your own `ServletContextListener`, which for every query gets the current tennant and stores it into your `ApplicationContextProvider` implementation.

Comment: So how would you inject controller with a service that depends on a tenant, mind showing controller code as well? (It is not obvious to me :( )

Comment: You inject your service into controller in regular way. But service is not declared as bean, but as factory bean. This factory bean creates proxy that delegates its calls to a real bean, decrlared in child context.

Comment: I added description of injection service into controller in my last edit

Answer (score 0):

The new tenant scope and a servicelocator can helps

Tenant scope will guarantee than service is created one time for a tenant

Sample code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="tenant" value="foo.TenantScope"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="service" class="foo.Service" factory-bean="tenantServiceLocator" factory-method="createInstance" scope="tenant"/>

<bean id="fooService" class="FooService">
<bean id="barService" class="BarService">

<bean id="tenantServiceLocator" class="foo.TenantServiceLocator">
    <property name="services">
        <map>
            <entry key="foo" value-ref="fooService"/>
            <entry key="bar" value-ref="barService"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

TenantServiceLocator should know the user tenantId

```
public class TenantServiceLocator {
    private Map<String, Service> services;

    public String getTenantId() {
        return "foo"; // get it from user in session
    }

    public Map<String, Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(Map<String, Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public Service createInstance(){
        return services.get(tenantId);
    }
}

public class FooController{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
}
```

A sample TenantScope implementation

```
public class TenantScope implements Scope {
    private static Map<String, Map<String, Object>> scopeMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        Map<String, Object> scope = getTenantScope(getTenantId());

        Object object = scope.get(name);
        if(object == null){
            object = objectFactory.getObject();
            scope.put(name, object);
        }

        return object;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getTenantScope(String tenantId) {
        if (!scopeMap.containsKey(tenantId)) {
            scopeMap.put(tenantId, new HashMap<String, Object>());
        }

        return scopeMap.get(tenantId);
    }

    private String getTenantId() {
        return "foo"; // load you tenantId
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
        Map<String, Object> scope = getTenantScope(getTenantId());
        return scope.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't find any documentation for tenant scope in Spring except in relation with Hybris.

Comment: I have omitted its implementation. Just added a sample to the answer.